# Why is print() not working anymore with python?

Tags: python

in fact this should not be a problem because it's fairly basic. I just want to print out an array of categories, but in one line and separated by comma.

```
for entry in categories:
    print(entry, ", ", end='')
```

Until now it worked perfectly but now it doesn't print anything. If I delete the last part `", end=''"` it works but then I can't get everything in one row without a new line for each category.

Can someone explain to me why it isn't working any more?

Comment: are you sure that `categories` is not empty? Call `print(len(categories))` before for-loop.

Comment: Sure I used breakpoints and the print out without ", end='' " and it works perfectly

Comment: which python version are you using ?

Comment: unrelated but `print(entry, end=', ')` would do the same thing, both versions would leave a trailing comma though

Comment: you could also use `print(', '.join(categories))`

Comment: @yamm depends what type each `entry` is... if they're not strings you'll need to explicitly make them so first...

Comment: @JonClements yes you are right. `print(', '.join(map(str, categories))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost certainly experiencing *output buffering by line*. The output buffer is flushed every time you complete a line, but by *suppressing* the newline you never fill the buffer far enough to force a flush.

You can force a flush using `flush=True` (Python 3.3 and up) or by calling the `flush()` method on `sys.stdout`:

```
for entry in categories:
    print(entry, ", ", end='', flush=True)
```

You could simplify that a little, make `,` the `end` value:

```
for entry in categories:
    print(entry, end=', ', flush=True)
```

to eliminate the space between the entry and the comma.

Alternatively, print the categories as one string by using the comma as the `sep` separator argument:

```
print(*categories, sep=', ')
```

Comment: Alternatively - instead of flushing each time, put a `print()` outside the `for` loop? Also - fairly sure you'd end up with trailing `, `s here... and the `sep` argument needs unpacking first...

Comment: @JonClements: I prefer the `sep` option anyway. In theory the `categories` iterable could be slow, at which point flushing the output each time you get a next entry could be helpful.

Comment: Still not sure about the trailing `, ` but @Eternal_Sunshine seems happy with it, so :)

Comment: @JonClements: their own version included the trailing comma and extra space. *shrug*.

Answer (score 0):

Check `categories` isn't empty - that'd make it print nothing - also I'd consider changing your code to make use of the `sep` argument instead (depending how large `categories` is):

```
print(*categories, sep=', ')
```

eg:

```
>>> categories = range(10)
>>> print(*categories, sep=', ')
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Then you don't have to worry about flushing/trailing separators etc...

Comment: That was not the exact answere to my question but it is a good solution anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Printing to the terminal in Python 3 is usually "line buffered". That is, the whole line is only printed to the terminal once a newline character is encountered.

To resolve this problem you should either print a new line at the end of the for loop, or flush stdout.

eg.

```
for entry in categories:
    print(entry, ", ", end='')
print(end='', flush=True) # or just print() if you're not fussed about a newline
```

However, there are better ways of printing an array out. eg.

```
print(", ".join(str(entry) for entry in categories))
# or
print(*categories, sep=", ")
```